# how to hide a button if no value in div

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

this is code which i try to change

```
<%if(request.getParameter("hiderefineproblem")==null){%>
        <input type="button" value="Refine Problem" onclick="return showHide();" style="background-color: #3399ff;color:#ffffff;" />
    <%}%>

    <div id="showHideDiv" style="display: none;">
        <p>Would one of the following diagnoses apply? Choose the most
            specific one:</p>
        <FORM ACTION="snomedMapping.jsp#newres" METHOD="POST">
        <%
            pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            pstm.setString(1, snomedid);
            pstm.setString(2, snomedname);
            resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
            boolean bSubmit=false;
            int refid=0;
            String[] pipe;
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                 refid=resultSet.getInt("refid");
                 pipe= resultSet.getString("mapRule").split("\\|");

                if (pipe.length > 1){bSubmit=true;
        %>      

            <input type="radio" id="radioList" value="<%=refid%>" name="refId"/>            
            <tr><%=pipe[1]%></tr>
             <br /> 

        <%
            }
            }           
        %>
        <%if(bSubmit){%>
        <input type="hidden" name='hiderefineproblem' value='yes'/>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit" style="background-color: #3399ff;color:#ffffff;"> 
        <%}%>
        </FORM>

    </div>

    <script>
        function showHide() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv");
            if (ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
         </script>
```

there is button its value is Refine Problem and i need not to show the button if there is no result for that button . the button contains some value from database .sometimes there is no value for that button . so that time i need not to show the button .

how to hide the on click button if the value is empty .

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question correctly, I believe you can give all the buttons a class and then iterate across all the buttons with javascript, checking the value each time, and if the value is nothing using javascript to `.hide()` that button

Comment: the think i need is there is one show/hide button if i click the button its show some content from database . if there is no content under the button then  button should not visible .

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Perhaps what you are looking for would be an ajax request to get data from the database. If nothing is returned, you can just hide the button